# Why my tuesdays are not included in my formula?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am completely new to Excel and Power Query.
I'm trying to automate a recurring task at work.
Essentially, I have orders and the day they are dispatched (column: DispatchDate).
I add a column on my end called Out of Delay Date, which takes into account 4 working days for the deadline (I don't count weekends, but I do count everything else, including holidays).
The formula works well EXCEPT when the DispatchDate is a Tuesday, and then it goes awry, and the Out of Delay Date falls on the following Sunday, whereas if we consider 4 working days, it should always be the following Friday.

Within the 4 working days, the DispatchDate is included.
Example: DispatchDate = Tuesday (1 working day), Wednesday (2 working day), Thursday (3 working day), Friday (4 working day)

Why do I have this issue only with Tuesdays? Why does the logic work everywhere else except for this particular day?

Here is my entire code (going to highlight the part we're interested in) :

```
AddBusinessDays = (startDate as date, numDays as number) as date => 
    let
        weekdayList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        daysAdded = List.Generate(() => [Count=0, Date=startDate], 
                                  each [Count] < numDays, 
                                  each let 
                                        nextDay = Date.AddDays([Date], 1),
                                        isWeekday = List.Contains(weekdayList, Date.DayOfWeek(nextDay, Day.Monday) + 1)
                                      in [Count=if isWeekday then [Count]+1 else [Count], 
                                          Date=nextDay]),
        lastDay = List.Last(daysAdded)[Date]
    in
        lastDay
in
    AddBusinessDays([DispatchDate], 5)),
    #"Lignes triées1" = Table.Sort(#"Personnalisée ajoutée",{{"Out of delay date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Type modifié2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Lignes triées1",{{"Out of delay date", type date}}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié2", "Updates", each ""),
    #"Type modifié3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée1",{{"Updates", type date}})
in
    #"Type modifié3"
```

I'm sorry if I'm retarded, I just don't understand why tuesday is an issue ?

Especially because the exact same formula taking into account 5 working days is working fine !! It's just because I want 4 working days, I really don't understand why.

Thanks for your time guys

I expected the result to be the same for every week days.

4 working days means if an order is generated on a tuesday, it should be displayed on the following friday in my out of delay date column.

Comment: The code is rather unreadable; could you please format it properly? On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: I'm sorry, indeed it was horrible. 
I also removed the part we're not interested in.
Sorry if the code does not make sense, I'm really new and don't understand sh*t in what I'm doing. I succeed for the 5 working days part but for this one I have no clue :/

Comment: Can you add a few more of the earlier lines to the code above, what come before the first line? Trying to see how this is added as a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach:

```
#"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtrer DispatchDate", "Out of delay date", each
  let
    day = Date.DayOfWeek([DispatchDate], Day.Monday),
    daysToSkip = if day > 4 then 7 - day else if day > 1 then 2 else 0
  in 
    Date.AddDays([DispatchDate], daysToSkip + 3), type date),
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: How did this go?